# Component returned failure code: 0x80004005

Tags: html, ajax, exception, mozilla

I'm trying to send "Get" AJAX request using an HTML file on my computer, but the following code returning me an "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005" exception on Mozilla browser.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://180.92.172.157/SMS-API/SMS-Push.aspx?UserName="+Username+"&Password="+Password+"&mobile="+Mobile+"&SenderName="+SenderName,false);
xmlhttp.send();
alert("HELLO");
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm    doing?

Comment: I didn't expect failure code 0x80004005, but I wasn't able to reproduce the problem locally so I'm none the wiser.

Comment: Are you using AdBlock?
Try disabling it.

Comment: @desmati Thanks man ! was struggling with this error for hours. I have used a parameter call 'adType', I think that name is the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Try reading through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

A quick Google seems to point to a security feature preventing cross-site scripting.

Comment: I have come across this many times and use IE for local development because you can customise the security settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is cross browser issue. 
Remove http or https and try it will work

You can check this link

http://tharindumathew.com/2012/05/16/xml-parsing-error-in-firebug/